# Есть ли в Sqlite оператор похожий на LIMIT который использует не число, а условие

Tags: sqlite

Есть необходимость выбрать подпоследовательность данных из таблицы, базируясь на разнице между timestamp соседних элементов. нужно выбрать такую последовательность, разница между таймстампами элементов которой не превышает 5 минут

Разобрался как выбрать саму разницу

```
select 
record_timestamp - (select 
    record_timestamp 
    from short_summary as ss2 
    where 
    (short_summary.record_timestamp - ss2.record_timestamp) / 60 <= 5 
    limit 1
) as diff, 
* from short_summary
```

Получаем все элементы с разницей в 5 минут. то есть столько подпоследовательностей, сколько есть в таблице. Но так, как последовательность нужна одна, то мне же нужен оператор, похожий на LIMIT,который обрывал бы выборку при определённом условии, например если id не соседние.

Comment: *последовательность нужна одна* Какими критериями она определяется? *нужен оператор, похожий на LIMIT* Обратите внимание на рекурсивный CTE.

Comment: @Akina Последовательность, включающая в себя все элементы, начиная с последнего, до того элемента (не включая) разница между которым и предыдущим больше 5 минут. То есть условно мне нужно оборвать выборку когда будет достигнуто это условие

Comment: То есть от записи с максимальным record_timestamp в направлении его уменьшения до "первого" зазора более 5 минут? Ну так CTE это выберет, не особо напрягаясь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схематично (ставить SQLite ради проверки синтаксиса не хочу):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(id, record_timestamp) AS
(
        SELECT id, record_timestamp
        FROM short_summary 
        ORDER BY record_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
    UNION ALL
        SELECT s.id, s.record_timestamp
        FROM short_summary s, cte
        WHERE s.record_timestamp < cte.record_timestamp 
          AND s.record_timestamp >= cte.record_timestamp - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
    ORDER BY record_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

Если в SQLite в рекурсивной части CTE используется весь текущий набор, а не только полученный на предыдущем шаге рекурсии - замените в рекурсивном подзапросе таблицу `cte` на подзапрос, получающий из неё самую старую по времени запись.

PS. Не знаю, поддерживает ли SQLite оператор INTERVAL. Если нет - замените на допустимое синтаксисом выражение.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. Уже сам что то подобное наваял, базируясь на https://blog.expensify.com/2015/09/25/the-simplest-sqlite-common-table-expression-tutorial/

Comment: @iamthevoid Угу, подход один и тот же... но обратите особое внимание на пояснение. Возможно, в рекурсивной части вместо таблицы `cte` придётся использовать что-то вроде `(select record_timestamp from cte order by record_timestamp asc limit 1) as cte1`...

Comment: хм, вопрос немного не по теме - но почему то когда использую order by и limit в query перед union all выборка ругается на то, что нельзя использовать их ДО union all, только после. Если убираю union all и выборку после него, то корректно возвращает одну строку. Не понимаю, в чём дело

Comment: Возможно, какие-то заморочки SQLite. Попробуйте обернуть начальный запрос: `SELECT * FROM (... LIMIT 1)`.

Comment: докопался до сути, одн проблема, последний ORDER BY record_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 он применяет к union all, а не к запросу, пришлось убрать и заменить union all на union, тогда все одинаковые результаты коллапсятся в один и получается прекрасная табличка.

Comment: select * from () получилось применить только к первому запросу, а к рекурсивной части не получается, потому что когда мы делаем select * from (select ) получается, что внутри рекурсивной части мы создаём дополнительную рекурсию, если я правильно понял сообщение от sql explorer

Comment: энивей я справился благодаря вам, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант (не проверял)

```
SELECT * FROM short_summary ss1
JOIN    (SELECT record_timestamp, 
            (SELECT record_timestamp FROM short_summary ss2 WHERE ss2.record_timestamp > ss1.record_timestamp ORDER BY ss2.record_timestamp LIMIT 1) record_timestamp_next 
        FROM short_summary ss1
        WHERE (SELECT record_timestamp FROM short_summary ss2 WHERE ss2.record_timestamp > ss1.record_timestamp ORDER BY ss2.record_timestamp LIMIT 1) - record_timestamp /60 <= 5) ss 
    ON ss1.record_timestamp = ss.record_timestamp or ss1.record_timestamp = ss.record_timestamp_next
ORDER BY ss1.record_timestamp
```

Comment: Не очень хочется вникать, та как решил проблему с помощью cte,но сам запрос наглухо убивает sql explorer, а мой ноутбук начинает активно охлаждаться) Думаю это должно сработать, поресерчу на досуге